# FAQ "Product Support" needs some TLC

Tags: bug, help-center

> **Related Meta.SE Question:**: [The “product support” page in Help Center does not make much sense network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238113/241497)

The [Product Support](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) "Can I support my product on this site?" FAQ page seems to be stating the default Stack Overflow wording:

> Code Review Stack Exchange can help support your product but it can't be the only support. There are issues that only you can address, and if you send your users to Code Review Stack Exchange for them they'll just get frustrated. Guide your users in where to ask what -- something along the lines of the following:
>
> **Types of questions and where to ask:**
>
> > - How do I? -- ask on Code Review Stack Exchange (tell them what tags to use -- your product tag at minimum)
> > - I got this error, why? -- ask on Code Review Stack Exchange
> > - I got this error and I'm sure it's a bug -- report it on your own site
> > - I have an idea/request -- report it on your own site
> > - Why do you? -- ask in your own community (support forum, etc)
> > - When will you? -- ask in your own community

I'm pretty sure the first two need some rewording TLC. Or maybe we need to add to them by saying they should go to Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, this particular article cannot be edited by moderators, so it would have to go straight to the community managers.

Comment: @Jamal Does that mean we have to wait for graduation?

Comment: It just means that an employee will have to edit that page as we cannot do it ourselves.

Comment: I guess the sample questions should be changed, But this will attract lot of broken code questions even after that. eh, The horror. For bad questions people who redirect the users will have to vote close it themselves instead of answering.

Comment: That page should just not exist at all for Code Review.

Comment: Ssssh, don't say anything, but [PCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) also has that page...

Comment: Heck, even [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) has it... wtf!?

Comment: Related: [The “product support” page in Help Center does not make much sense network-wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238113/241497)

Comment: @rolfl Good thinking!

Comment: I like a good derp or two in the morning, just before my coffee (working on this)

Comment: [Question is still current](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8921/52915)