# Inapplicable help page

Tags: bug, help-center

[This page (Can I support my product on this site)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) is Stack Overflow's corresponding help page with names exchanged - saying "Code Review" instead of "Stack Overflow". It doesn't belong here. [This page (How to not be a spammer)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) links to it.

In fact, [the "Our Model" section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange) has links to the following pages that really don't make sense for Code Review, and should probably be removed:

- [Product Support](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)
- [What does "beta" mean](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta)

Further, the "Spam page" has links that have the URL in full format instead of as a named hyperlink, i.e. it looks like:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer instead of [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) (This is especially ironic since it is in the section about posting links appropriately ;-).

Note that this problem is common to all sites other than the *Overflow sites. Do these sites really need a section of help dedicated to finding bugs in products?

- [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)
- [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)
- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)
- [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)

Note that this is raised as an issue, but not fixed, on meta.se: [The "product support" page in Help Center does not make much sense network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238113/the-product-support-page-in-help-center-does-not-make-much-sense-network-wide)

Further, it is ironic, that the above meta post has a link to a previous post here on Code Review: [FAQ "Product Support" needs some TLC](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/faq-product-support-needs-some-tlc)

Comment: That seems to be an artifact of the Stack Exchange site managements (e.g. it's also included on [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/product-support), [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) and [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/product-support))